# Set Interval not working the way I want

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I want to make an AJAX call about 2000ms. My AJAX is fired up once user clicks on anchor tag. So after that I want that AJAX to run every 2000ms.

```
setInterval(function(){
$("a[name=device_submit]").click(function(event){
    var get_url = $(this).attr('href');
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({url:get_url,
     success:function(data){
         var data = JSON.parse(data);
         latitude = data[0].fields.latitude;
         longitude = data[0].fields.longitude;
         initialize(latitude, longitude, 15);
  }});
});
}, 2000);
```

Problem is, it's running lot of times, when I click it, it stops then. Then again when I click it it runs lot of times.
What's wrong?

Comment: You have put the _binding_ of the event handler to the element(s) into your interval … that is most likely _not_ what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't constantly re-bind your click handler, if you're looking to fire off AJAX every 2 seconds, something like the following should do. I added a flag so that the AJAX won't fire until you first click the button (untested, the braces may be off)

```
var flag = false;

var url = $("a[name=device_submit]").attr('href');

a["name=device_submit]").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    flag = true;
});

setInterval(function(){
 if(flag){
  $.ajax({url:url,

   success:function(data){
     var data = JSON.parse(data);
     latitude = data[0].fields.latitude;
     longitude = data[0].fields.longitude;
     initialize(latitude, longitude, 15);

  });
 }
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your interval is *binding the event handler* each time it fires.

Swap `setInterval` with `click`

```
$("a[name=device_submit]").click(function(event) {
    setInterval(function() {
        var get_url = $(this).attr('href');
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: get_url,
            success: function(data) {
                var data = JSON.parse(data);
                latitude = data[0].fields.latitude;
                longitude = data[0].fields.longitude;
                initialize(latitude, longitude, 15);

            });
        }
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: `click` won't solve the problem. Remember I want it to run every `2000ms`

Comment: @user2032220 — I said *swap* them, not *use only click*.

Comment: Oppsy. Let me try and get back to you.

Comment: It's all good sir, Unless there's a problem. It's taking 2 seconds even when I click on the button for the first time. Is it a way to handle this?

Comment: Move the function expression outside the interval arguments. Make it a function declaration. Call that function immediately. Then pass it to `setInterval`.